# Find the derivative of this function at $x_o = \pi$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of $g(x)= (\tan \left|x\right| + x )\sin(x) $ at $x_o = \pi$.

I tried to solve it using $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, but I got stuck at this point:

$\lim_{h \to 0} \ \frac {\tan \left|\pi+ h\right| + \pi+h )\sin(\pi+h)-\tan \left|\pi\right| + \pi )\sin(\pi)}{h}$.

Since $h \to 0$, it seems to me that the derivative is $0$, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: why don't you just use the product rule?  There's no need to go all the way back to the definition.

Comment: but wouldn't there be a problem with the absolute value of x?

Comment: try plotting $\tan|x|$, you'll see that it's actually differentiable in a neighborhood of $\pi$.

Comment: $|x|$ only has a problem at $x=0$. And even so, you could split it into two cases, both of which are differentiable (with possible discontinuity where you glue them together).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the product rule:

$$g'(x) = (\tan^2 |x| +1) \sin x + \cos x \tan|x| + \sin x + x\cos x$$
$$g'(x) = \tan^2 |x| \sin x  +\sin x + \cos x \tan|x| + \sin x + x\cos x$$
 at $x_0= \pi$

$$g'(\pi) = -\pi$$

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \ \frac {(\tan \left|\pi+ h\right| + \pi+h )\sin(\pi+h)-\tan \left|\pi\right| + \pi )\sin(\pi)}{h}=$$
$$=\lim_{h \to 0} \ \frac {(\tan \left|\pi+ h\right| + \pi+h )\sin(\pi+h)}{h}=$$
$$=\lim_{h \to 0} \ (\tan \left|\pi+ h\right| + \pi+h )\frac{-\sin h}{h}=\pi \cdot (-1)=-\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you're computing the derivative at $\pi$, you can safely disregard the absolute value, because $x$ is positive in a neighborhood of $\pi$, so in such a neighborhood of $\pi$ you have $\tan\lvert x\rvert=\tan x$.

The product rule now tells you
$$
f'(\pi)=(1+\tan^2\pi+1)\sin\pi+(\tan\pi+\pi)\cos\pi=-\pi
$$

It would be different if the derivative at $0$ is to be computed.